# Rails 5 after submitting form / action stay on exactly the same spot on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this webshop, and on one page you see

1. `products`;
2. with a submitting form for a `booking`;
3. your `order` with its `bookings`;
4. with a removing link for a `booking`;
5. and an updating form for a `booking`.

Both the `order.bookings` and the `products` make potentially long lists on a html page.

The whole booking works by only a booking_controller.

What the `booking_controller` does:

- Takings in the (new) params of a single booking or the destroy action.
- Saves the new order.
- Redirects to the store.

Works fine, just using **ruby** and `html.erb`.

Only problem, and this really needs to change, is that obviously after each redirect the browser goes to the top of the page. The browser isn't focussed. Or better to say, the browser should remain, but doesn't.

I get that your doing all these things on the server-side, so a page reload, or better to say, data-refresh, is necessary. What I don't want is building this whole thing again on the client-side (JS).

Can't I simply say something like: *after data refresh redirect to exact same spot on page*. Ignoring all the difficulties an asynchronous request would give, or am I exaggerating and is a little JS easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Rails, using ajax is very easy however if you're not familiar with ajax at all it can be a bit daunting at first.  Luckily there are many tutorials on the subject.  Basically, add the `remote: true` option to your form_for statement and rails will automatically understand you want it to make a 'POST' request in JS format.  It's important to realize that the incoming HTTP request is in JS format because you'll then need to specify handling that event in the controller.  Such as:

```
   def create
     #Do whatever saving and processing you need here
     respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to some_path_here }
        format.js { } #By not adding anything in the brackets here, you're telling rails to fetch a js view file that follows standard rails convention and so it should be named 'create.js.erb'
   end
```

Then in your controller's views folder create the view file `create.js.erb`.  In that file you'll want to refresh whatever part of the page needs updating which usually involves hiding the old div that was there and appending a partial in its place. I usually leave an empty div with an ID on the page (in this case your `new_whatever_page.html.erb` that I then call in the js.erb file to append a partial to:

In your create.js.erb add:

```
$("#the-id-of-the-div-in-your-new-view-page").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'order_table') %> #This basically says, find the div on the current page with a matching id and then append the partial named _order_table.html.erb to it.
```

Now just make a partial named

> `_order_table.html.erb`

in the same views folder and put whatever content you want to insert or update.

Comment: It works with: $('#order').html("<%= j render 'orders/order' %>") ! :) Next issue would be how not to have multiple bookings of the same product show up on the page, but merge them into one. Thanks!

Comment: BTW is the respond_to block necessary, because it also works without?

Comment: the respond_to block is good practice since it makes it obvious you're expecting js and also allows you to handle requests in other formats if necessary.